# Authorization fails when trying to access Google Drive from a service (PHP)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I need to get a list of files from a public marked folder on Google Drive.

Even though the folders are marked as public, the Drive API by design requires my code to send an authenticated request – fair enough.

However, I am not being authorized correctly. Instead I get an error: "Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error": "unauthorized_client" }', and I cannot see why.

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';

// session_start();

define('DRIVE_SCOPE', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL', 'blablablablabla-blablablabla51@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH', 'Bla-blabla29db83.p12');

/**
 * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
 * that acts on behalf of the given user.
 *
 * @param userEmail The email of the user.
 * @return Google_Service_Drive service object.
 */
function buildService($userEmail) {
  $key = file_get_contents(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array(DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $auth->sub = $userEmail;
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  // This fails:
  if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  }
  return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}

/**
 * Print files belonging to a folder.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param String $folderId ID of the folder to print files from.
 */
function printFilesInFolder($service, $folderId) {
  // Omitted code
}

$service = buildService('blablabla@gmail.com');
printFilesInFolder($service, 'blablablablablablablabla');
?>
```

The service email account and the pkcs12 files are correctly entered.

I'm thinking of the $userEmail address. Is there somewhere where I should create a relation between the service and that address? Currently I'm using the mail address that owns the project and has set up the OAuth2 certificate being used.

This uses the newest Drive API. I have found other questions and explanations but they usually rely on the obsolete Documents API instead.

I am trying to run the code from the command line, not from a web page.

Comment: Did you do domain wide delegation with service account check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: I tried to follow the directions, yes, but it suggests going to admin.google.com. However, when I log in it just takes me back and asks me to log in again. It kind of goes into a loop and never shows the control panel. This happens on all browsers and with whatever credentials I use.

Comment: Are you admin for your admin console?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. This is what I did: 1) Created a google account, 2) Created a project on developers.google.com, so I am the owner of that project. What should I do to become 'admin for my admin console'?